# jScrollPane strange behavior in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jScrollPane with fallowing page: http://demo.2klika.net/home.php#!pages/prodavaonice.html

Well, this works as expected in all major browsers except in Internet Explorer (I tried with IE7 and IE8). On first load (same goes for every page reload), IE will show list of locations, and when you click somewhere in that list, it will jump down to the last item in list. After that it will work normally (you can click on title, eg. Mesnica 1, Mesnica 2, etc..., and script will center google map on that marker).

I tried everything that I can think of (eg. removing onClick handlers for various elements, tried to catch problematic function using developer tools in IE, googling around, but no luck).

If someone can help with this, I will be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been addressed:

[jScrollpane 2 IE8 Problem - strange behavior when hit top/bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388058)

https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/commit/b80165e3c5cb6d21f9569cacaffd55d33435d23c

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.

See https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues/issue/34 for more details.