# jScrollpane 2 IE8 Problem - strange behavior when hit top/bottom

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jscrollpane

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html and maybe in other demos, but also in my site :(

on IE8 (maybe also 6/7) and the example "BOTH", drag the bar to a absolute position, top or bottom then click on the div, you`ll get scrolled to the top of the page or the div..
this only happens if you used the mouse click and NOT the wheel

i dont know how to fix this, im using the api.reinitialise(); but apparently thats not the problem

i can post my code if necessary but its even on the demos so..btw you can also see the scroll automoving when you hit alt+tab in the window (in my site)

### #

oh, found another user with the same problem
[jScrollPane strange behavior in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366315/jscrollpane-strange-behavior-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Is this only happening in IE? I can't look in IE now (I'm on a mac) but am interested to find a fix (I'm the author of jScrollPane so obviously want to make sure it works in all browsers!). When you say "click on the div" in your description which div do you mean?

Comment: only in IE (7,8)...the div was the content from the "both" example..another example is here: demo.2klika.net/home.php#!pages/prodavaonice.html scroll to bottom using your mouse (not the wheel, drag the bar by holding the left button) then click on the content

Comment: https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues/issue/34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the jScrollPane repository:

https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/commit/b80165e3c5cb6d21f9569cacaffd55d33435d23c

Grab the latest code from github or my site and it should all work fine. Thanks for the bug report!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you add the jScrollpane-Function. In div inside each other:

```
$(function() {
    $('.scrollpane_outside').jScrollPane();
});

$(function() {
    $('.scrollpane_inside').jScrollPane();
});
```

Try:

```
 $(function() {     $('.scrollpane_outside').jScrollPane(); });

 $('.scrollpane.inside').jScrollPane();
```